# Is it possible, on exception retry the consumer after 10 min and this should happen for 4 times

Tags: spring-boot, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

I have implemented the kafka consumer as follows

```
@Bean
public Consumer<Message<String>> input(){
return -> {
// external service call
};
}
```

if any exception occurs in external call or in consumer, I want to retry consumer after 10 min. can any one tell me how to achieve this. I have few of the SO links and spring docs. I didn't understood perfectly. I am new to this and want to try it.

links i gone through

https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/Elmhurst.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/index.html#_retry_template

[Backoff settings for spring cloud stream rabbit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51916293/backoff-settings-for-spring-cloud-stream-rabbit)

[Spring cloud stream kafka consumer error handling and retries issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70389035/spring-cloud-stream-kafka-consumer-error-handling-and-retries-issues)

**Update** **:**
I have added below properties but on exception it retrying consumer more than 8 times and the interval between retry is 1 sec only

```
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.poppyPants.consumer.maxAttempts=2
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.poppyPants.consumer.backOffInitialInterval=900000
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.poppyPants.consumer.backOffMaxInterval=900000
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.poppyPants.consumer.backoffMultiplier=1.0
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.poppyPants.consumer.defaultRetryable=false
```

**Update2** below are my config properties in console

```
00:51:17.996 [pool-8-thread-2] INFO  o.a.k.c.consumer.ConsumerConfig - ConsumerConfig values: 
    allow.auto.create.topics = true
    auto.commit.interval.ms = 5000
    auto.offset.reset = latest
    bootstrap.servers = [server.domian:9092]
    check.crcs = true
    client.dns.lookup = use_all_dns_ips
    client.id = consumer-fsf-gateway-5
    client.rack = 
    connections.max.idle.ms = 540000
    default.api.timeout.ms = 60000
    enable.auto.commit = true
    exclude.internal.topics = true
    fetch.max.bytes = 52428800
    fetch.max.wait.ms = 500
    fetch.min.bytes = 1
    group.id = group_id_val
    group.instance.id = null
    heartbeat.interval.ms = 3000
    interceptor.classes = []
    internal.leave.group.on.close = true
    internal.throw.on.fetch.stable.offset.unsupported = false
    isolation.level = read_uncommitted
    key.deserializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArrayDeserializer
    max.partition.fetch.bytes = 1048576
    max.poll.interval.ms = 300000
    max.poll.records = 500
    metadata.max.age.ms = 300000
    metric.reporters = []
    metrics.num.samples = 2
    metrics.recording.level = INFO
    metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
    partition.assignment.strategy = [class org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.RangeAssignor]
    receive.buffer.bytes = 65536
    reconnect.backoff.max.ms = 1000
    reconnect.backoff.ms = 50
    request.timeout.ms = 30000
    retry.backoff.ms = 100
    sasl.client.callback.handler.class = null
    sasl.jaas.config = null
    sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd = /usr/bin/kinit
    sasl.kerberos.min.time.before.relogin = 60000
    sasl.kerberos.service.name = kafka
    sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.jitter = 0.05
    sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.window.factor = 0.8
    sasl.login.callback.handler.class = null
    sasl.login.class = null
    sasl.login.refresh.buffer.seconds = 300
    sasl.login.refresh.min.period.seconds = 60
    sasl.login.refresh.window.factor = 0.8
    sasl.login.refresh.window.jitter = 0.05
    sasl.mechanism = GSSAPI
    security.protocol = SASL_SSL
    security.providers = null
    send.buffer.bytes = 131072
    session.timeout.ms = 10000
    ssl.cipher.suites = null
    ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2, TLSv1.3]
    ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = https
    ssl.engine.factory.class = null
    ssl.key.password = null
    ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509
    ssl.keystore.location = null
    ssl.keystore.password = null
    ssl.keystore.type = JKS
    ssl.protocol = TLSv1.3
    ssl.provider = null
    ssl.secure.random.implementation = null
    ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX
    ssl.truststore.location = null
    ssl.truststore.password = null
    ssl.truststore.type = JKS
    value.deserializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArrayDeserializer
```

any thing wrong? any extra config required @Gary Russell any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

You can use several `retry` properties of [ConsumerProperties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/current/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#_consumer_properties), such as `maxAttempts`, `backOffInitialInterval`, `backOffMaxInterval` and `backOffMultiplier`. This will use the default `RetryTemplate`. If you need to further customize you can provide your own implementation of the [RetryTemplate](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/current/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#_retry_template)

Comment: does this properties works for only exception case until the request success / limit reached? if it success i dont want to retry it. i just want retry for exception case only.

Comment: Yes, those properties only apply when your consumer method throws an exception.

Comment: i have added these properties but the retry happening more than 8 times which is not as excepted spring.cloud.stream.bindings.poppyPants.consumer.maxAttempts=2
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.poppyPants.consumer.backOffInitialInterval=900000
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.poppyPants.consumer.backOffMaxInterval=900000
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.poppyPants.consumer.backoffMultiplier=1.0
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.poppyPants.consumer.defaultRetryable=false

Comment: updated question with my changes